# Casting a QDialog to QWidget

Tags: pyqt4

I lost my .ui file, and it seems pyuic4 cannot make a .ui file out of a .py file, only the other way around.

I have a QDialog, and I am now instead going to put its content inside a tab-pane. For that I need a widget, not a "stand-alone" dialog.

How can I cast QDialog to QWidget, or is there any other workaround other than doing the whole design over again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a custom class that drives from QDialog, but you would now like to use it inside a tab pane rather than standalone.

For that the simplest path is to change your class to inherit from QWidget directly rather than QDialog. There should be little to no code change in that class (except for the obvious stuff in the constructor).

(I have no idea what your .ui problem has to do with this though.)

Also, QDialog inherits from QWidget. No type-casting necessary to use a QDialog when a QWidget is expected.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but first time it didn't work because I forgot to change some minor things. Now it works:) The .ui file being missing was a problem because I could easily open QTDesigner and do it from there. Again thanks!